# primeng p-chart y-axis label getting trimmed

Tags: angular

I made a p-chart and the label on y-axis is long such that it gets trimmed. Is there any way I can wrap the text so that some part of text goes to another line [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YsL1.png)...Code

```
export class ViCcfPercentageRevenue extends ViChart {

  constructor() {
    super("line");
  }

  static override buildChart(): ViChart {
    let chart = new ViCcfPercentageRevenue();
    let legend = {display: false};

    let xAxesPeriod = {
      axis: 'x',
      grid: {display: false}
    };

    let yAxesRate = {
      beginAtZero: true,
      border: {display: false},
      axis: 'y',
      display: true,
      position: 'left',
      title: {display: true, text: Label.QUALITY_MEASURE_SCORE + '(%)'},
    };

    let yAxesPaymentRate = {
      beginAtZero: true,
      border: {display: false},
      axis: 'y',
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      title: {display: true, text: Label.PAYMENT_RATE_PERCENT},
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function (val: any) {
          return ChartService.scaleValueFormat(val, Label.PERCENTAGE_CONSTANT);
        }
      },
    };

    function wrapLabel(label: string): string {
      const words = label.split(' ');
      console.log(words)
      // Wrap on two lines
      if (words.length > 1) {
        return words[0] + ' ' + words.slice(1).join(' ');
      }

      return label;
    }


    return chart.withLegend(legend, true)
      .withBaseAxes('x', xAxesPeriod, true)
      .withDisplayAxes("score", yAxesRate, true)
      .withDisplayAxes("paymentRate", yAxesPaymentRate, true)
      .isResponsive(false)
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  transformAndSetChartData(data: CcfQualityDto[]): Observable<boolean> {
    if (data !== undefined) {
      this.assignAndTransformData(data);
    }
    this._isChartRenderedSubject.next(true);
    return this._isChartRenderedSubject;
  }

  private assignAndTransformData(data: CcfQualityDto[]): void {
    this._data = data;
    let chartLabels: string[] = Util.extractPaymentTermLabels(data);
    let minPaymentRate: any[] = [];
    let maxPaymentRate: any[] = [];
    let score: any[] = [];
    let empty: CcfQualityDto ={incurredTerm: '',
      qualityMeasureName: '',
      rate: 0,
      qualityMeasureId: '',
      qualityMeasureScore: 0,
      minPaymentRate: 0,
      maxPaymentRate: 0}
    data.push(empty);
    data.forEach(item => {
      if (item.incurredTerm !== undefined && chartLabels.indexOf(item.incurredTerm) > -1) {
        if (item.qualityMeasureScore != null) {
          score.push({x: item.incurredTerm, y: item.qualityMeasureScore});
        }
        if (item.minPaymentRate != null) {
          minPaymentRate.push({x: item.incurredTerm, y: item.minPaymentRate});
        }
        if (item.maxPaymentRate != null) {
          maxPaymentRate.push({x: item.incurredTerm, y: item.maxPaymentRate});
        }
      }
    })

    let chartDataSets = [{
      label: Label.QUALITY_MEASURE_SCORE,
      backgroundColor: '#F1B61A',
      borderColor: '#F1B61A',
      borderWidth: 3,
      data: score,
      yAxisID: 'score',
      type: 'line',
      pointStyle: true,
      pointRadius:4,
      pointHoverRadius:7,
      order: 1
    }, {
      label: Label.MIN_PAYMENT_RATE,
      backgroundColor: '#c0efc4',
      borderColor: '#81E589',
      data: minPaymentRate,
      barThickness: 22,
      yAxisID: 'paymentRate',
      type: 'line',
      pointStyle: true,
      pointRadius:4,
      pointHoverRadius:7,
      order: 2,
      fill:1
    },

      {
        label: Label.MAX_PAYMENT_RATE,
        backgroundColor: '#c0efc4',
        borderColor: '#70C377',
        data: maxPaymentRate,
        barThickness: 22,
        yAxisID: 'paymentRate',
        type: 'line',
        pointStyle: true,
        pointRadius:4,
        pointHoverRadius:7,
        order: 3,
        fill:1
      },

    ];
    // @ts-ignore
    this._chartData = {labels: chartLabels, datasets: chartDataSets};
  }
}
```

and html part -- >

```
<p-chart [data]="paymentStream.subType === subType.CCF_PERCENTAGE_REVENUE ? viCcfPercentageRevenueChart.getChartData() : viCcfQualityChart.getChartData()" [options]="paymentStream.subType === subType.CCF_PERCENTAGE_REVENUE ? viCcfPercentageRevenueChart.getChartOptions() : viCcfQualityChart.getChartOptions()" height="100% !important"
                     type="line"
                     width="100% !important"></p-chart>
```

I want the Label.QUALITY_MEASURE_SCORE (marked yellow in image) be wrapped such the label does not gets trimmed and shows one after another